# Why the Hashcode of the HashMap is Zero

Tags: java, performance

I am trying to initialize with Approach One:

```
Map<String, String> mapInter = Collections.EMPTY_MAP;
mapInter = new HashMap<String, String>();
mapInter.put("one", "one");
System.out.println(mapInter.hashCode());
```

Approach  two :

```
HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>(10);
myMap.put("key", "value");
System.out.println(myMap.hashCode());
```

In first approach when i print hashcode it's print zero, but in second approach it print hash code. after initialization hashcode will be returned.

Why the HashCode in the first Case Printed zero but not in the second case?

Comment: whats the question?

Comment: What's your request? I can't understand.
To initialize a map just do a new HashMap()

Comment: Approach three: 
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String,String>(10);

Comment: What the use of Collections.EMPTY_MAP in initialization.

Comment: As a sidenote, `HashMap` will use the nearest higher power of two in the initial capacity, so you might want to write `new HashMap<...>(16)`. Agreed this doesn't change much.

Answer (score 5):

The `HashCode` will be 0 only if the both `Key` and `value` are same.

**It is happening because of the hashcode implementation of Entry inside HashMap, Which is as follows:**

```
public final int hashCode() 
{
  return (key==null   ? 0 : key.hashCode()) ^ (value==null ? 0 : value.hashCode());
}
```

**It performs `^` on the hashcode's of  both key and value, which always returns 0. if both are same.**

In your example if you change the `myMap.put("key", "key")` then both map's  will return hashcode 0.

```
Map<String, String> mapInter = Collections.EMPTY_MAP;
mapInter = new HashMap<String, String>();
mapInter.put("one", "one");     
System.out.println(mapInter.hashCode());
```

Approach two :

```
HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>(10);
myMap.put("key", "key");
System.out.println(myMap.hashCode());
```

**Output:**

```
0
0
```

Answer (score 2):

The use of `Collections.EMPTY_MAP` in initialisation, as you've used it in Approach One, is **nothing**.

You assign the `EMPTY_MAP` field to a variable, but then immediately overwrite it.  Your code would be identical if you didn't perform this first assignment at all, e.g.:

```
Map<String, String> mapInter;
mapInter = new HashMap<String, String>();
mapInter.put("one", "one");
```

or

```
Map<String, String> mapInter = new HashMap<String, String>();
mapInter.put("one", "one");
```

The value that a variable *used to have*, has no bearing on the current object's hashcode.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend approach three:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(10);
map.put("key", "value");
```

That way you only need to modify one thing if you decide not to use a `HashMap` after all.

Answer (score 0):

1st line in the below code is redundant, since you are overriding it in the 2nd line.

```
Map<String, String> mapInter = Collections.EMPTY_MAP;
mapInter = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

the above code is equal to

```
Map<String, String> mapInter = null;
mapInter = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

this is also equal to

```
Map<String, String> mapInter = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Collections class consists exclusively of static methods that operate on or return collections. Noe for your `Collections.EMPTY_MAP`. It is equivalent to calling following method

```
/**
 * Returns the empty map (immutable).  This map is serializable.
 *
 * <p>This example illustrates the type-safe way to obtain an empty set:
 * <pre>
 *     Map&lt;String, Date&gt; s = Collections.emptyMap();
 * </pre>
 * Implementation note:  Implementations of this method need not
 * create a separate <tt>Map</tt> object for each call.   Using this
 * method is likely to have comparable cost to using the like-named
 * field.  (Unlike this method, the field does not provide type safety.)
 *
 * @see #EMPTY_MAP
 * @since 1.5
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static final <K,V> Map<K,V> emptyMap() {
    return (Map<K,V>) EMPTY_MAP;
}
```

and

```
public static final Map EMPTY_MAP = new EmptyMap<>();
```

So basically it returns a Map with no data.